# Visio + Visual Studios

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visio

I currently have a license to visual studio 2010 pro.  I always liked visio, but the price has been pretty high to invest.  I know that it can work with VS to auto generate classes and also reverse engine VS projects to visio maps.  Problems is last I looked it was only for Visual Studio Team Edition.

My question is are there any actual advantages Visio provides for VS2010 Pro / any features that can be used between the two, or is it just limited to VS2010 Team / Ultimit.

I will be purchasing before the 1st if the two can work side by side. Simply explanations on how you can use it and benefits is much appreciated!  Again I only have VS 2010 pro

Thanks in advance!